# how to shorten the breadcrumb when it appears in mobile website

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

when i view my website in mobile with lot of filters, the breadcrumb length becomes too large. so i want to replace all the li tags that are behind the second last li. that means all the li except first, last and last-1 li need to be replaced with dots.

Anybody can help me fix this with jquery, javascript, or css?

```html
<ul class="left">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Airways</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Trauma</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Medical</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OB | Peds</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Patient Assessment</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Proprietary</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Trauma</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Medical</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OB | Peds</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Patient Assessment</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Proprietary</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is just example code i have added here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jquery like this.  Basically if it is a smaller width device, and if it is not first, last or second last child, the text of the link tag is replaced by '..' .

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {  

            if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) 
            { 
                // The viewport is less than 768 pixels wide 
                console.log("This is a mobile device.");                     
                $('ul.left li').each(function() {
                    $this = $(this); // cache $(this)                     
                    if (! $this.is(':first-child') && ! $this.is(':nth-last-child(2)') && ! $this.is(':last-child')    ) {
                          $this.find('a').text("..");
                    }                       
               });                  
            }     
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer on stack overflow, hope this is what you want this is the codepen link

https:// codepen.io/vatzkk/pen/yLYMJeG

HTML

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<ul class="left" id="bread">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Airways</a></li>
 <li id="dropdown" style="display:none">
   <div class="dropdown" >
  <i class="dropbtn">...</i><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-list">

  </div>
</div>
  </li>
        <li><a href="#">Trauma</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Medical</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OB | Peds</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Patient Assessment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Proprietary</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trauma</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Medical</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">OB | Peds</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Patient Assessment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Proprietary</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Javascript

```js
//you can add your conditions over here 

document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display="block";
var arr=[...document.getElementById("bread").children];
var dropdownItems=arr.slice(2,-2);

dropdownItems.map(item=>{
  document.getElementById("bread").removeChild(item);
  document.getElementById("dropdown-list").appendChild(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pure CSS** Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3o8vuwd6/2/

First give your list a class

```
<ul class="left breadcrumblist">
```

CSS:

```
/* This is just to give it some styling as you haven't given any */
.breadcrumblist li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}
.breadcrumblist li + li::before{
  content: "/";
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}


/* adjust to your breakpoint. 9999 just so it works on large screen as an example */
@media only screen and (max-width: 9999px)  { 
  /* hide all */
  .breadcrumblist li{
    display: none;
  }
  /* show first and last */
  .breadcrumblist li:first-child,
  .breadcrumblist li:last-child{
    display: inline-block;
  }

  /* add ... to the end of the first one */
  .breadcrumblist li:first-child::after{
    content: "...";
    padding-left: 0.5em;
  }

  /* fiddle with the content we added in styling */
  .breadcrumblist li + li::before{
    content: "";
    padding-right: 0;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your guidance and finally i made something work according to my requirement and also i want to share it here because in case in future if someone looks for the same issue he or she can be benefited from this. This is also from the modifications that all you have just posted above.

```
<ul class="left" id="bread_cumb">
 $(document).ready(function(){
        if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)").matches) 
        
            var width = $(window).width();
            if (width < 720) {
               
            $('#bread_cumb li:not(:first-child):not(:nth-child(2)):not(:last- 
            child):not(:nth-last-child(2))').html('<span style="margin- 
            left:7px;margin-right:7px;">  ...  </span>');
            var last =$('#bread_cumb li:last-child').text();
            var re = /^([A-Za-z0-9_'",.!@#$%^&*()-+=?/\|:]+)[\s,;:]+([a-z]+)/i;  
                var m = re.exec(last);
            $('#bread_cumb li:last-child').html('<a>'+m[1]+' '+m[2]+'...</a>');
               
            }
          });
Thanks all for your valuable ideas.
```